# Regex problems in TextMate

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

Regular Expressions are new to me (yet they are wonderful and useful :D). However, after trying to use them in TextMate, I'm getting unexpected results. I'm not sure if that's a bug or that's how regular expressions work.

I have this code

```
begin text in the middle end and more text and a
second begin second text in the middle end
```

Searching with `begin.+end` I would expect two results

1. `begin text in the middle end` and
2. `begin second text in the middle end`

But I get the whole text selected; I would expect `begin.+end` to search for `.+` until the first `end` is found, but it searches until the last one.

Is that how they work? Where could I learn how to use regular expressions?

The truth is I'm interested in just selecting the inside `.+` without `begin` and `end` but that's another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex to get the strings between begin and end,

```
(?<=begin).+?(?=end)
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/oX4qT1/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=begin)` Positive look-behind is used to match after a specific pattern. In this, regex engine sets the matching marker just after to begin.
- `.+?` Matches one or more characters.`?` makes the regex non-greedy so it would results in a shortest match.
- `(?=end)` Once it finds the string `end`, regex engine stops matching. Thus giving you the characters between begin and end.

Comment: The key was `.+?` ;) The rest is just something that I need to learn.

Comment: @Manuel added exp for `.+?`

Comment: see the difference by adding and removing `?` in this demo http://regex101.com/r/oX4qT1/3